How to use ggplot to generate doubly-grouped side-by-side boxplot?
I am trying to generate a doubly-grouped side-by-side boxplot that is each airport(Origin) has two boxplots, and y axis is the flight duration.
My data frame is sba_connections_boxplot that looks like the following:

Here is my codes to generate a doubly-grouped side-by-side boxplot:
    ggplot(sba_connections_boxplot, aes(x = ORIGIN,
             y = ACTUAL_ELAPSED_TIME,
             fill = Direction)) +
  geom_boxplot(staplewidth = 0.5) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 12) +
  ggtitle(
    "Distribution of Flight Durations for SBA Flights",
    subtitle = "Grouped by airport and direction"
  )+ 
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45)
  )+
  ylim(-100, 500) +
  labs(x = "airport", y = "Flight duration")

Here is my output:

Here is what the ideal graph should look alike:

Clearly, in my graph, each airport only has one Direction type, but they are supposed to have two. In addition, my box plots are shrunken vertically.
Please point out how I can fix my boxplot so that it looks as beautiful as the ideal output. Thanks

Can you provide some data?

Like this (using some made-up data) with position = position_dodge()?
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

# toy data
df <- tibble(
  elapsed = rnorm(100, 150, 50),
  origin = rep(c("DFW", "PHX", "SBA", "SEA", "LAX", "PDX", "SBA", "PHX", "SFO", "SMF"), 10),
  direction = sample(c("destination", "departure"), 100, replace = TRUE)
  )

df |>
  ggplot(aes(origin, elapsed, fill = direction)) +
  geom_boxplot(staplewidth = 0.5, position = position_dodge()) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 12) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45)) +
  labs(
    title = "Distribution of Flight Durations for SBA Flights",
    subtitle = "Grouped by airport and direction",
    x = "airport", y = "Flight duration"
    )


Created on 2024-04-20 with reprex v2.1.0

Do you really need position = position_dodge() ?

The OP's ideal plot looks dodged so the above may be what they're looking for.

Yes, but you can achieve this without dodging since "fill" is an aesthetic.
